# Count/Sum results using case and limit in mysql

Tags: mysql

Trying to create a query that gives me the total wins, draws and losses.  I have the following query

```
SELECT CASE 
    WHEN m.home_team = '192'
        AND m.home_full_time_score > m.away_full_time_score
        OR m.away_team = '192'
        AND m.home_full_time_score < m.away_full_time_score
        THEN 1
    END AS 'wins',
CASE 
    WHEN m.home_team = '192'
        AND m.home_full_time_score = m.away_full_time_score
        OR m.away_team = '192'
        AND m.home_full_time_score = m.away_full_time_score
        THEN 1
    END AS 'draws',
CASE 
    WHEN m.home_team = '192'
        AND m.home_full_time_score < m.away_full_time_score
        OR m.away_team = '192'
        AND m.home_full_time_score > m.away_full_time_score
        THEN 1
    END AS 'loss'
FROM exp_tm_matches m
INNER JOIN exp_tm_division_matches dm
    ON (dm.match = m.id)
INNER JOIN exp_tm_divisions d
    ON (dm.division = d.id)
WHERE m.info = 'PL'
    AND (
        m.home_team = '192'
        OR m.away_team = '192'
        )
    AND dm.season = '16'
ORDER BY m.kick_off DESC LIMIT 5
```

This produces the following

```
wins        draws       loses   
NULL        1           NULL
1           NULL        NULL
1           NULL        NULL
Null        1           NULL
1           NULL        NULL
```

What I am trying to get is Wins = 3 Draws = 2 Loses = 0, If I add count to the case statements It ignores the LIMIT of 5.

Comment: If you add "Count" to this, it will only return a single record... How could it return 5 records? Do you want the records to be grouped by matches, or team or something?

Comment: I want to return the total amount of wins, draws and loses for the last 5 matches for the particular team.  Adding count in the case statements gives me all wins, draws and loses and ignores the limit of 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation.  You are almost there:

```
SELECT SUM( (m.home_team = 192 AND m.home_full_time_score > m.away_full_time_score) OR
            (m.away_team = 192 AND m.home_full_time_score < m.away_full_time_score
            )
          ) as wins,
       SUM(m.home_full_time_score = m.away_full_time_score) 
          ) as draws,
       SUM( (m.home_team = 192 AND m.home_full_time_score < m.away_full_time_score) OR
            (m.away_team = 192 AND m.home_full_time_score > m.away_full_time_score
            )
          ) as losses
FROM exp_tm_matches m INNER JOIN
     exp_tm_division_matches dm
     ON dm.match = m.id
WHERE m.info = 'PL' AND
      192 IN (m.home_team, m.away_team) AND
      dm.season = 16;
```

Notes:

- You don't use the divisions table, so I removed that join.
- If the ids are numeric, you should not use quotes around the constants.
- You should not use single quotes for column aliases.  You don't need any escape characters for these names, so I removed them.  In fact, only use single quotes for string and date constants.
- MySQL has a nice feature where boolean values can be treated as 0 for false and 1 for true, eliminating the need for `if()` or `case`.
- The logic for `draws` does not require looking at the team code.
- You only want one row back with summary information, so the `limit` is unnecessary.

To get the last five matches, then change the `from` and `where` clauses to:

```
FROM (SELECT m.*
      FROM exp_tm_matches m INNER JOIN
           exp_tm_division_matches dm
           ON dm.match = m.id
      WHERE m.info = 'PL' AND
            192 IN (m.home_team, m.away_team) AND
            dm.season = 16
      ORDER BY m.kick_off DESC
      LIMIT 5
     ) m
```

Comment: This is what I get if I add Count around the case statements but I want to get the last 5 matches and what this does is give me all matches for that team.

Comment: that's excellent thank you. could you help me expand that so that i can include sum of all goals scored for that team

Comment: Could you help me expand the above so that I can include goals scored.

Answer (score 0):

You also need to add some brackets in your AND OR AND statements since it will not work this way.

```
   WHERE m.home_team = '192'
    AND m.home_full_time_score < m.away_full_time_score
    OR m.away_team = '192'
    AND m.home_full_time_score > m.away_full_time_score
```

Gives as result: Home or away team have a score.

might work better as:

```
    WHERE (m.home_team = '192'
    AND m.home_full_time_score < m.away_full_time_score)
    OR (m.away_team = '192'
    AND m.home_full_time_score > m.away_full_time_score)
```

Gives as result: Home team has a score < away OR (home team when playing as) away team has a score > away

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution is the following:

```
SELECT SUM(wins) as total_wins,
 SUM(loss) as total_losses,
 SUM(draws) as total_draws
FROM
( 
...add your complete query here, but you ahve to add a column we can group the results by 
i.e.: SELECT m.home_team AS team
) temp
GROUP BY team
```

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

I have had to do similar things. I am not a heavy development type guy but this worked well for me. I modified the first bit of your query based on an old query of mine. It worked well for the sample data I created

```
SELECT 'wins' = sum(CASE 
WHEN m.home_team = '192'
    AND m.home_full_time_score > m.away_full_time_score
    OR m.away_team = '192'
    AND m.home_full_time_score < m.away_full_time_score
    THEN 1 else 0 end)
,  

'draws' = sum(CASE 
WHEN m.home_team = '192'
    AND m.home_full_time_score = m.away_full_time_score
    OR m.away_team = '192'
    AND m.home_full_time_score = m.away_full_time_score
    THEN 1 else 0 end)
,  

'loss' = sum(CASE 
WHEN m.home_team = '192'
    AND m.home_full_time_score < m.away_full_time_score
    OR m.away_team = '192'
    AND m.home_full_time_score > m.away_full_time_score
    THEN 1 else 0 end)
```